# 1/r Counting Rate for Radiation Experiment

Tags: homework-and-exercises, experimental-physics, nuclear-physics, radiation, data-analysis

In an experiment performed in the lab, I want to justify that, when the width of the Geiger counter window is approximately the same size as the distance between the window and a mildly radioactive source of Sr-90, we have a $1/r$ dependence of the counting rate. I know that we should have $1/r^2$ dependence by the inverse square law, but how do I show that, if r is relatively small, we obtain $1/r$ instead? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Presumably related to http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/80871/inverse-square-law-in-beta-radiation

Comment: Can you pop the raw data somewhere we can grab it e.g. on Google drive, or even here if there isn't too much of it. We don't normally offer a data analysis service, but you have me intrigued now :-)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the paths the electrons take though the active region of the counter...when the face of the counter is very near the source some of electrons will just clip the active region of the detector and may not leave enough (or any) ionization in the working gas (this is a statistical process, after all).

So the (acceptance times efficiency) goes down (various sources lump this effect into one or the other of those terms).

Not sure what the exact conditions are to get $1/r$, but how sure are you that the exponent is exactly $-1$ and not simply "weaker than $1/r^2$"?

The effect should get smaller as the detector gets increasingly far from the source, disappearing completely in the limit of range much larger than the size of the window.

---

This is the effect I alluded too in the last comment I made on your earlier question.

Comment: I am pretty sure it is -1...I plotted the counting rate vs one over distance, and I got a perfectly linear best fit. As well, I am supposed to derive a formula that explains this effect for small r. How would I go about deriving such a formula if I don't know how many electrons "clip" the active region of the detector?

Comment: You start by assuming a particular geometry for the source and the active region of the detector---make both as realistic as possible---and then examine the geometry of the situation. An estimate of the amount of detector gas that must be traversed to get a even chance of registering will also be needed. Each part of the source should radiate uniformly in all directions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possibility:

[image: Counts]

Assuming this is related to your previous question, you measured the distance from 1 to 10cm. The blue line shows a log log plot of the counts using an inverse square law, and as expected it's a straight line of gradient -2.

The magenta line shows the results if the measured distance is less than the actual distance from the source to the detector. This can happen because the electrons may be coming from below the surface of your source, and they may be detected beyond the end of the GM tube. I fiddled with the offset to get an average gradient of -1, and this happened at an offset of about 3.4cm.

However, using the distances from your previous question there is significant curvature. Whether you could see this or not depends on your error bars.

**Later:**

On reflection, there is an easier way to check for a distance offset. Suppose you are measuring a distance $d$, and this is shorter than the real distance by some constant offset $d_0$. Then:

$$ Counts \propto \frac{1}{(d + d_0)^2} $$

So:

$$ d = \frac{1}{\sqrt{Counts}} - d_0 $$

So just graph $d$ against $1/\sqrt{Counts}$ and you should get a straight line. The $y$ intercept will be $-d_0$.